# Why is wheel scrolling event not firing when mouse is over a "position: fixed" element?

Tags: css, scroll, css-position, mousewheel

Here is a simple test case for my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/JZmvf/20/

- put mouse over the red square
- scroll with mouse wheel
- the parent div is not scrolling

How to make the parent div normally scroll with mouse wheel, even when the mouse is over the position: fixed element ?

Thanks.

Comment: It scrolls fine in Windows 7/IE9, but doesn't scroll in Chrome.  Even if you solved it for one browser, you could face the same problem across different platform/browser combinations so I wouldn't bother trying to fix it if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

Its very late for an answer but I was able to overcome this problem by adding `pointer-events: none` style to the "fixed" div.

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JZmvf/55/

Comment: You've saved my life man! I'm implementing a drag and drop library in react, and have been dealing with this for days

Answer (score 1):

Elements with `position: fixed;` are positioned relative to the viewport, so the `scrollable` div is not the parent of the `fixed` div in this case, even though it may appear that way if you're just looking at the output.

If you position your cursor over the `fixed` div and scroll down, your browser is being told to scroll down the `fixed` div. Fixed elements, by nature, are not scrollable, so nothing happens.

You may want to add a few more details about exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `pointer-events: none` seems to work as long as you don't need any event in the fixed div

If you need events on it I found 2 solutions:

- Handling your page scroll on the html tag because it will capture the scroll event even on a fixed element which is easy but limiting
- Using `position: sticky` instead so the scroll event bubbling happens normally but you'll have to work on the CSS because sticky doesn't exactly do the same as fixed